# Why is that a conjecture is written and its proof can not be done for years?

Tags: soft-question, intuition, conjectures

Why is it that if a conjecture is written and its proof can not be done for years, means if its statement is understandable in language, why is the proof not possible if the conjecture is correct?
E.g., the proof of Fermat's last theorem (which was very clear what is it saying) was done 350 years later than it was conjectured and it took 130 pages.
Fermat couldn't think for 130 pages and then give the conjecture. So why is the proof so horrible for such simple equation?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  There are some statements in number theory that are simple to make and understand but very difficult to prove or disprove

Comment: I think your reasoning is fallacious.  Just because a problem is easy to state, that is no reason to think it should be easy to solve.  "Fly a person to Alpha Centauri."  There, that was easy to write and is easily understandable.  Is it easy to accomplish?

Comment: because it is sometimes easier to make a guess from observing a certain pattern  than to prove it (and such conjectures may still fail - for long time, people conjectured that the ugly parallel axiom can be proved from the other axioms of geometry, and no-one found a proof - until it became evident that the conjecture was wrong) . There is also a lot of survivor bias in this: Many conjectures are quickly resolved (one way or other) and will never be noticed by you as a long-standing open problem.

Comment: One of the seven millennium problems has been solved. (The Poincaré conjecture, proved by Perelman.)

Comment: If it's such a mystery, then go ahead and solve the 7 clay problems.

Comment: Also, there really is no way to be certain that there _isn't_ a simpler solution to problems like FLT. It's just that we haven't found a significantly shorter way to do it yet. Of course, on the flip side there might _not_ be an easier way to do it.

Comment: Did you have any reason to assume that a statement that is easy to formulate and easy to understand must be also easy to prove ? Nate's comment hits the nail on the head. Of course this is not the case.

Comment: @JairTaylor Sometimes, an extremely difficult conjecture is solved, yes. But what has this to do with the question ?

Comment: @Peter Was just responding to the OP, who originally wrote that "Morover, 7 millenium problems are still unsolved." before an edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is in fact a precise sense in which this situation can't be avoided: we can prove that (unless ZFC is inconsistent) there is no computable function $F$ such that every ZFC-theorem of length $n$ has a ZFC-proof of length $\le F(n)$.

- Here "ZFC" is just the generally-accepted set of axioms for mathematics (we need to fix some set of axioms to rigorously talk about proofs in the first place). Incidentally, the fact above is itself provable in ZFC (and indeed galactically less).

This is a consequence of Godel's incompleteness theorem: if we had a computable proof-length-bounding function $F$, we could use it to build a computable complete consistent extension of ZFC (this is a good exercise).

So there will always be "short" theorems with only "long" proofs.

(Technically this only addresses the *length* issue as opposed to the *time* issue. But it should be clear that the theme is the same: computability-theoretic barriers prevent any sense in which "simple" questions can always have "simple" resolutions, even if we restrict attention to questions which are answerable in the first place.)

---

That said, this doesn't address the fact that there are **interesting** examples of theorems (like FLT) which we naturally think of as much shorter than their proofs. The argument above doesn't rule out the possibility that "natural" mathematical questions always have "not-too-long" proofs. But frankly that's too subjective an issue to be rigorously addressed.

Comment: I was thinking of doing something with Godel here, but this answer is better than anything I would have written. +1

Comment: I think that when a person put on a true conjecture (we have verified it to be true) ,proof must came in his mind in the form of what we called intuition. I mean if his saying is universally correct how can it be a fluke?  Can it be true that he just forgot the whole process of arriving to his conjecture or just couldn't fill all the gaps in form of mathematical axioms. Shouldn't we call that a proof in philosphical terms?

Comment: I can prove Goldbach's conjecture that way, I forget how ... oh wait that apparently counts as a proof under this model @ANUJGUPTA

Comment: @ANUJGUPTA "I think that when a person put on a true conjecture (we have verified it to be true) ,proof must came in his mind in the form of what we called intuition" Absolutely not: some conjectures are just false. We form conjectures based on, well, conjecture: hopefully-good guesses based on limited information. " Shouldn't we call that a proof in philosphical terms?" No, we shouldn't.